# error while installing "npm install -g ionic cordova"

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

When I install  `npm install -g ionic cordova It throws below error`

> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to
>   /usr/lib/node_modules npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules npm ERR!
>   code EACCES npm ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! syscall access npm ERR! Error:
>   EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules' npm ERR!  {
>   Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules' npm
>   ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   \'/usr/lib/node_modules\'', npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code:
>   'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'access', npm ERR!   path:
>   '/usr/lib/node_modules' } npm ERR!  npm ERR! The operation was
>   rejected by your operating system. npm ERR! It is likely you do not
>   have the permissions to access this file as the current user npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please
>   double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing
>   directories, or try running npm ERR! the command again as
>   root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/javauser/.npm/_logs/2018-05-19T04_42_24_737Z-debug.log

I tried with root user as well.
I am using `node v9.11.1  , npm 6.0.1`

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Never use npm with sudo (or as root)! You can create potential backdoor to your system.

Answer (score 0):

I have just answered a very similar question in the following link: [How to fix the problem with vue.js instalation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67183891/how-to-fix-the-problem-with-vue-js-instalation/67204248#67204248)

Basicaly what is happening is that NPM does not have the privileges to access /usr/local/lib. To give it access, you could change the ownership of ~/.npm in order to belong to your current user. This could be this way:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`

This way you do not have to run npm as sudo, which is not recomended. I believe that it is due to vulnerabilities that are known in npm packages.

Here is an article about it: [Don't use "sudo" with npm "install"](https://dev.to/brylie/don-t-use-sudo-with-npm-install-56p9#:%7E:text=Using%20%22sudo%22%20when%20installing%20NPM,sudo%22%20when%20installing%20NPM%20packages.)

Answer (score -1):

run with sudo in Mac OS or linux

```
sudo npm install -g ionic cordova
```

or in windows open cmd with run as administrator

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```